# I have lost the venv part of my agnoster prompt on Apple Mac

Tags: mac, zsh, python3, virtualenv

macOS 10.12.6 Sierra

Hello, I have just installed `Zsh` and `Oh-my-zsh`. I then selected the Agnoster theme and was very happy with it. Now, after some tweaking I seem to have lost the venv part of my Agnoster prompt.

In fact I think that the problem is more to do with my `venv` and `python3` setup for the following reason.

If I try to activate a Python venv, it doesn't seem to work because `which python3` still gives the default `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so I guess that the `Agnoster` prompt is faithfully reflecting the `venv` state.

I have tried deleting the existing `venv` folder and creating a new one with `python3 -m venv ./venv`, and then running `./venv/bin/activate`, but no joy.

I'm still quite new to Apple Macs so please excuse any ignorance this question may betray!

Just to recap, then, how can I get my `venv` working and how do I restore the `venv` part of my Agnoster prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the source of the activate script closely enough. You are supposed to run it via `source ./venv/bin/activate` not `./venv/bin/activate` by itself!

Comment: How about you accept your own answer, so this question doesn't stay open?

Comment: How about someone explaining why I haven't been notified about this question for 3 years and six months, unti yesterday and today. Plus, the patronising and snarky tone of your comment is exemplefies why I, and many others who actually have some social skills, have grown to hate anything connected with Stack Overflow. Have a nice life 

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across as snarky and/or patronizing. That was not my intention at all. 